# What is origin of the word 'do'?

Tags: etymology

What is origin of the usage of the word 'do' when in reference to a social event (primarily in Britain)?

For example a 'Stag do' or 'Christmas fundraiser do'.

Comment: Is this the same idea as 'hairdo'?

Comment: @Mitch There used to be a British TV show, in the late 80s I believe, entitled "[A Bit of a Do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Bit_of_a_Do)" starring David Jason, every time there was a wedding, or any special occasion there would be a formal party, a get together of friends and relatives. A bit of a do, is an expression which emphasizes the event, something special, fancy. Something that takes a bit of time and effort to set up, organize and **do**.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - OK. That sort of usage isn't very common in the US.

Comment: I was also searching for the root word, and base meaning for the word "do". I was actually searching whether it's anyway related to 'two', as in 'two hands'. Found no relevance so far. (I strongly believe there could be some link).

Comment: Related: [How and when did “bash” and “do” come to mean party?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225267/how-and-when-did-bash-and-do-come-to-mean-party)

Answer (score 2):

The OED says for "do" 2b:

> Something done in a set or formal manner; a performance; *esp*. an entertainment or show; a party; hence (orig. *jocular*), a military engagement, raid, or other ‘show’. Orig. *dial*. or *vulgar*.